# Dump DirectShow filter graph to image or text file

Tags: c++, windows, directshow

For debug/logging purposes I'd like to see what my filter graph looks on a client's PC. For this I added code to [dump the graph](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd377551%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to a graphedit file, but the problem with that is you can only view on a PC that has the exact same filters installed. Is there some way to dump the graph as an image (like a graphedit screen shot) or even just a text file (filter1 > filter2 etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in capability to dump a graph. What you mention is not a dump of the graph exactly, and it is rather its persistent state. To discover the effective topology you eiher:

1. enumerate filters and connections yourself in code (to log to file etc)
2. put your graph on running object table in code, then connect with external tool (GraphEdit, GraphStudioNext etc), including generation of text/picture to share further; note that you need proppage.dll from Windows SDK to have this running
3. [temporary] install (COM register with regsvr32) [DirectShowSpy](http://alax.info/blog/777) which does #2 for already built application, that is no need to add code for publishing graph

   - if your code can detect Spy presence then you can skip proppage.dll thing and generate extensive textual graph dumps from code, with connections, media types etc - [see this post](http://alax.info/blog/1460) for details and C# code snippet
   - or, DirectShowSpy-aware code might load spy explicitly and attach a graph to it to get text information, in which case no spy registration is necessary (Spy is not for production environment; then its registration requires administrative privileges otherwise unnecessary)
   - when registered, even without proppage.dll, spy logs graph activity including topology information to DirectShowSpy.log file in either `CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA` or `CLSID_APPDATA` directory.

Comment: Thanks Roman, I had hoped to get a reply from you as I know your DirectShowSpy, however it is not a solution for me as I cannot install software like that on client machines (nor ask them to operate it). Same goes for using ROT (in fact I have that implemented, but just for myself).

Comment: With no standard API for that, once has to either do the job in code in full, or add a third party thing. I myself certainly use spy for the mentioned task. The spy's interference with Windows is at the time of COM registration, and my point here is that an application can even utilize its troubleshooting capabilities without registering it. Without ability to drop in third party stuff, I am afraid you are only with solution to enumerate yourself, go one by one through filters, write that into log file - all in your code.

Comment: Happen to have a link to a piece of code that does that? Really don't want to have to reinvent that. Either to enumerate everything, or convert graphedit file to something independant.

Comment: The closest I am aware of: [graph-studio-next/TextInfoForm.cpp](https://github.com/cplussharp/graph-studio-next/blob/master/src/TextInfoForm.cpp), `CTextInfoForm::DoFilterList`.

Comment: Or even better, same project and they way it does .GRFX files - they are readable in editor and you can also open them with the application.

Comment: Thanks Roman. However that program has a GPL licence so I cannot use their code.